# Is it possible to upload files directly to the Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I have written a file upload for larger files that is uploading the files to the Cloud Storage. Unfortunately this takes a while, because the Files are uploaded to the web server first, and then again from the web server to the Google Cloud Storage. Is there a way to upload files directly to the Cloud Storage with the Google PHP Api Client (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)? I couldn't find anything on this topic in the docs.

Comment: If I needed uploading larger files to google then I'd go for the Google Compute Engine. Why not try it? Did you try it already? Wasn't it good?

Comment: read the official docs not the php wrapper. Yes there is a way to upload directly from client without going throu server.

Comment: How you solve this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an upload URL with the name of your bucket, and the upload will go directly into that bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this isn't possible with the php wrapper (see Zig Mandels Comment).